# Hidden iframe problem

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, comet

In IE6 (but also seen in 7 and to a lesser extend 8) I have a problem with my code. I utilise a hidden iframe for Comet streaming. Sometimes when someone manually refreshes the page in Internet Explorer, they don't get the parent page but are taken by the browser to the hidden iframe URL.

Anyone seen this before or have any suggestions as to how to stop this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Suspecting more and more this is an undocumented bug in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell this is a bug in the browser. I have since 'fixed' this issue by explicitly handling this in the code.